# Import dataset from other query at Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

In Python Script, is there a way to import a dataset from another query?
For example, I wanna run a python script in "Tabela" query, but I need to use data from the others query ("Saldo" e "Reserva").

Screenshot from Power BI Query Editor:
[image: Screenshot from Power BI Query Editor]

Considering this Python script is a step from "Tabela" query transformation, 'dataset' refers to "Tabela" table. My point is how can I access "Saldo" table and "Reservas" table from this Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very happy about share that I figured out how to do it!

[image: Quest Done (screenshoot)!]

And this is the code (it is so simple):

```
let
    Fonte = #table({"Nome", "Tabela"}, {{"Reservas", Reservas}, {"Saldo", Saldo}, {"Pedidos", Pedidos}})
in
    Fonte
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

First merge your queries (tables) in the Query Editor and then apply your Python script on the result.

Comment: I think I understand. Could you, please, give me a example how to merge the tables as different datasets?

Comment: If you actually understood it, you could easily do it yourself. This will not be a PowerBI beginner course.

Comment: I understood your concept/strategy, but I don't know how do it.
Sorry my bad English.